# How do I use the Form's constructor to populate a List Box with data from an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

How do I use my Form's constructor to populate a `Listbox` with data from an Array in C#? So far this is what I have in my Name Class

```
String[,] strSpecialCakeName = {
                               {"Holiday Cake at", "$18"},
                               {"Birthday Cake at", "$25"},
                               {"Wedding Cake at", "$40"},
                               {"Super Hero Cake at", "$30"}
                               };
```

And this is what I have in my Form

```
public partial class frmLabSeven : Form
{
    private string[,] strSpecialCakeName = new string[4, 2];

    public frmLabSeven()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        strSpecialCakeName [0, 0] = "Holiday Cake at $18";
        strSpecialCakeName [1, 1] = "Birthday Cake at $25";
        strSpecialCakeName [2, 2] = "Wedding Cake at $40";
        strSpecialCakeName [3, 3] = "Super Hero Cake at $30";
    }
}
```

I know I can use the Collection in Item right on the Form, but that is not what I want to do. I just don't know how to get the data to show on the List Box using Arrays.

Comment: How would you add a single item to a listbox?  Figure out that code, then put it in a for/foreach loop and do it for each pair in the array.

Comment: Do you just want to iterate through both dimensions and add them to the list box?

Comment: @Servy so would it be something like lstSpecialCake.Text = strSpecialCakeName[0, 0] = "Holiday Cake at $18";

Comment: @Paronity yes that is all I want to do at this time. Thanks

Comment: @Kiviuq No.  You don't want to set the text of a listbox.  In fact, you should pretend that listbox doesn't even have a text property; it doesn't make sense for a listbox to have a text property at all; the only reason it has one is that it's inherited from `Control`.  You should probably start by looking at the documentation for `Listbox`, as the MSDN page(s) tend to have examples of how to use it.  If that fails, consider doing some web searches for `adding items to a listbox`.  It should give you an example of the method(s) you'll need to use.

Comment: @Servy, yes that's right. I should have known that. I'll take a look cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to be aware of is that your array looks like this:

```
strSpecialCakeName[0,0] = "Holiday Cake at"
strSpecialCakeName[0,1] = "$18"
strSpecialCakeName[1,0] = "Birthday Cake at"
strSpecialCakeName[1,1] = "$25"
strSpecialCakeName[2,0] = "Wedding Cake at"
strSpecialCakeName[2,1] = "$40"
strSpecialCakeName[3,0] = "Super Hero Cake at"
strSpecialCakeName[3,1] = "$30"
```

You can use a for statement to add it to your listbox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(strSpecialCakeName[i, 0] + " " + strSpecialCakeName[i, 1]);
}
```

Comment: Right because of the 2d array. That makes sense. I completely forgot about .Add okay thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really should have known this already, but thank you. Now it makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through both dimensions would be fairly simple, but I'm not sure it's going to give you what you think it is. Note @Mark Hall comment.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strSpecialCakeName.GetLength(0); i++)
    lstTest.Items.Add(strSpecialCakeName[i, 0]);
for (int i = 0; i < strSpecialCakeName.GetLength(1); i++)
    lstTest.Items.Add(strSpecialCakeName[0, i]);
```

Also, note that your assignments in the constructor are going to error due to index being outside the bounds of the declared array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Paronity. Also thanks for pointing me towards the documentation on MSDN. Cheers